# How can I get my div to stay fluid while inside another div without over lapping?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs (logoarea and navarea) inside a bigger div (id=header). How do I make navarea be fluid (resize if the page is resized) without making it overlap into div logoarea? I'm new to stack overflow and its formatting is a bit confusing, so ill just leave a jsfiddle link with my code, I think it's better anyway. Help is greatly appreciated, here is my code(All of my code including the HTML is on the jsfiddle link):

```
#navarea {
  width: 630px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/070zgvq2/

Comment: Just a recommendation, you can use Bootstrap to do responsive layout stuff, otherwise you may drive yourself crazy.  http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can resize them using media queries like this-

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px){

 #navarea {
/* change size */
      }
 }
```

This will work for devices that have screens less than 480px wide.
Also i'd recommend not using pixels but percentages for sizes to make it more responsive! 
Hope it helps.